# coupling of distributions vs joint distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, coupling

For continuoues variables, how is a coupling of two distributions different from their joint distribution? Are they the same concepts?

Update: Coupling is the same as defining a joint distribution on the Cartesian product space of the supports of original random variables, in a way that marginals of the defined joint distribution are equal to the original random variables. What am I missing?

Comment: Coupling of distributions has no relation to joint distributions.  Coupling refers to taking random variables defined on different prob. spaces on putting equivalent variables (same distribution) on a single prob. space.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)

Comment: Even your explanation still seems like defining a joint distribution on the product space of the supports of original random variables, in a way that marginals of the defined joint distribution are equal to the original random variables. What am I missing?

Comment: My understanding is that coupling means defining random variables on the same probability space with the same distribution as those on separate spaces.  This is my reading of the wikipedia reference.  I personally am not familiar with the term "coupling distributions"..